# ActiveX Textbox on Excel sheet change border and font when lost focus

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, activex

I have a problem with ActiveX Textbox on MS Excel as images below:

On focused:

[image: On focused]

But, when losted focus, it show incorrect font:

[image: Lost focused]

Can you tell me how to correct the issue?

Comment: Please share some code that we might be able to help you

Comment: Hi Quintin, I just added the control without any code. I have tried to open the excel file on others PC, and surprise, there are some PC don't have the issue.